# How do you change scenes using EditText in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

In my project, I am trying to change to different scenes depending on the number typed into an EditText. For example, it will launch as giving you 1 random number, and the EditText is default at 1, but if you want to have several random numbers at once, it will change scenes to go to a different layout.

I know to change scenes you use;

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class));
```

My trouble is with the if statement, if I use

```
    if (value == 2);
```

It returns to me as "Cannot resolve symbol 'if(boolean)'"

Thank you for your time,

Lane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, by "Scenes" you mean to say you want to switch to a particular "activity" according to the number you type in the Edittext. If this is what you want to achieve, then you should add a text watcher to your edittext and monitor the value that is entered in the edittext onTextChange.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.length() > 0) {
                //do something like showing a toast or changing the activity

                if (charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    //do something
                } else if (charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon `;` from your `if(value == 2);` statement

It should be like:

```
if (value == 2) {
    //do something here
}
```